# Ubuntu slows down even after cpu-intensive process is ended

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

After a Skype video call, or the use of virtualbox, Ubuntu slows down to a crawl, even after the process is ended.  Running htop reveals that processes that used little CPU before are now all using about 30% cpu (namely Compiz, Firefox, Python, and Skype, but I'm sure there are others), to the point where all my cores are at 99%.  All I can do from here is restart.

Any idea why this is happpening?  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on 3.7 GiB of memory, Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 330 @ 2.13GHz × 4, VESA: M92 graphics driver.  Not sure why I'm running VESA, I installed fglrx, but I suppose that's a different question.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
So I ran across this again after playing a youtube video and backing up at the same time.  I decided to run `unity --replace`
I received the following error:

```
(compiz:23601): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc0009e!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a1!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a4!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a7!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000aa!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000ad!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000ad!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000b0!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
(compiz:23601): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

So I ran `unity --reset` and looked into htop.  It seems that a "compiz --replace", Firefox, Skype, htop, Xorg, and rythmbox were using an abnormal amount of CPU, and everything was rather laggy.
Top displays the following:

```
top - 23:44:08 up  8:30,  2 users,  load average: 1.42, 2.15, 3.15
Tasks: 205 total,   1 running, 201 sleeping,   0 stopped,   3 zombie
Cpu(s): 29.7%us, 13.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 56.3%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.4%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3909324k total,  3713056k used,   196268k free,    78096k buffers
Swap:  4049916k total,   120360k used,  3929556k free,  2063860k cached
```

That amount of free memory concerns me.

Comment: I assume that's memory-intensive, too. Maybe your swap is used up too much. What is the output of `free`? in that case the pages will need time to swap back to RAM. Until then your PC may remain slow.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not swap.  I just got this problem recently after running updates.  The updates are finished, but now htop shows compiz, rhythmbox, lightdm, firefox, and plugin-container (for firefox) using more than 10% of CPU each.
Here is the output of free
`             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:       3909324    3675560     233764          0      92416    1968604
-/+ buffers/cache:    1614540    2294784
Swap:      4049916          8    4049908
`

Comment: I'm thinking about rebooting, as this is getting painfully slow.  Since I can't figure out how to format the output of free, have a screenshot: http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/umkwguwj/Selection_003.png

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/HighCPU#Problem%3a__High_CPU_Due_to_Software_Rasterizing); since you are using VESA driver, I think this is your case. Check the output of `glxinfo | grep render` and if it says `OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer` then this behaviour is normal until you use the appropriate video driver.

Comment: OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4300 Series
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image,

Comment: Sorry to double post.  I think I am using fglrx, and am suffering Bug #879522, in which VESA is incorrectly reported in System Information.  I'm not experienced enough to know.